# Even columns in document with long bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, vertical-alignment, two-column

I am writing a document in two column format and the last two pages are devoted to the bibliography, which I generate with BibTeX. I need to finish the last page with the two columns having the same size. I am lost at that point.

I have tried to use `\enlargethispage{-X cm}` finding X by trial and error. The problem is that when using that command after the call to `\bibliography{MyBib}`, the outcome is not the expected one: bibliography items span along all the first column and there is no column adjustment. I found out that if I write the command before `\bibliography{MyBib}` everything works as expected, but the problem is that the bibliography takes two pages so I can't do that, the only possibility is writing `\enlargethispage` afterwards. Could you please help me on that?

---

I self-answer :-) I suceeded by manually editing the .bbl file. If you have a smarter solution please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be very useful to know what document class you're using and how you get two column format.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I use \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} and inside the template IEEEtran I found these options \ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,twocolumn,oneside,final,journal}

Comment: Is the paper to be submitted? In this case I wouldn't bother if the submission instructions don't ask for balancing the columns in the last page.

Comment: It is a camera ready version, which is not going to be edited because it directly goes to a conference proceedings. The two columns issue is indicated by the conference guidelines. Up to the date I never had any problem in achieving that with \enlargethispage but this case is special for the rather long bibliography section. I am wondering if the only solution is not using bibtex, and instead of that, write each bibitem individually and then I write the command in the middle of them...

Answer (score 9):

The `IEEEtran` class has a trick for doing what you want in a simple fashion; here's an example, where I used a large bib database available in TeX Live.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum} % some mock text

% the following commands are just to avoid errors
\newcommand{\mkbibquote}[1]{``#1''}   
\newcommand{\hyphen}{\-}
%%%

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A. U. Thor}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

% this will issue a column break just before reference 68
\IEEEtriggeratref{68}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}


\end{document}
```

A couple of attempts gave a quite good result. The columns are not perfectly balanced, but doing it would split a reference.

[image]

Alternatively you could try

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\IEEEtriggercmd{\enlargethispage{-3in}}
\IEEEtriggeratref{60}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
```

which gives the following "balancing"

[image]

The `\IEEEtriggeratref` command places, by default, a column break before the specified bib entry; with `\IEEEtriggercmd` you can change the default command.

Comment: Brilliant, that is definitely what I was looking for, I wasn't aware of those commands in IEEEtran. Thanks so much.

Comment: Happy to have helped. Please, have a look at the [site's faq](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @Carlgar: you might consider to mark this answer as solution.